# MySQL union - how do I show table 1 content in all rows?

Tags: mysql, union

In the following mysql query I'd like to know if it's possible to get the rows from table aitisi to display in place of the blank values from table members. Thing is, I need to create a union but also display data of the first table in all rows.

```
select a1.id, a1.name, a1.surname, a1.program, a1.date
from aitisi a1 
union select a.id, m.name, m.surname, null, null from members m 
join aitisi a on (a.id = m.symbid)
```

I used null as dummy fields so I could perform a union with equal number of columns.
But this way I'm getting date and program only in the rows from table aitisi and the rest are blank.

Comment: Have you checked out a recursive join?

Comment: Do you have anything connecting the program and date information to you members table? foreign key?

Comment: Could you provide a couple of sample rows for each table and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not very efficient):

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.surname,
       coalesce(u.program, aa.program),
       coalesce(u.date, aa.date)
  FROM (SELECT a1.id, a1.name, a1.surname,
               a1.program, a1.date
          FROM aitisi a1 
         UNION
        SELECT a2.id, m.name, m.surname, NULL, NULL
          FROM members m
          JOIN aitisi a2 ON a2.id = m.symbid) u
  JOIN aitisi aa ON aa.id = u.id;
```

Looking more on your initial query, what would be wrong with this variant:

```
SELECT a1.id, a1.name, a1.surname, a1.program, a1.date
  FROM aitisi a1 
 UNION
SELECT a2.id, m.name, m.surname, a2.program, a2.date
  FROM members m 
  JOIN aitisi a2 ON a2.id = m.symbid;
```