# Mysql query with union and where

Tags: mysql, union, where-clause

In the following query I want to add a where statement to narrow the results to those with `m.extracard>0` :

```
SELECT u.id, u.onoma_u, u.name_u,
coalesce(u.programa, a.programa) as programa,
coalesce(u.barcode, a.barcode) as barcode,
coalesce(u.plan, a.plan) as plan,
coalesce(u.im_exp, a.im_exp) as im_exp,
coalesce(u.symb, a.symb) as symb
FROM (SELECT a1.id, a1.onoma_u, a1.name_u, a1.programa, 
             a1.barcode, a1.plan, a1.im_exp, a1.symb
      FROM aitisi a1 
      where a1.id between 6017 and 6063
      UNION
           SELECT a2.id, m.name, m.surname, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
           FROM members m 
           JOIN aitisi a2 ON a2.id = m.symbid 
           WHERE m.extracard > 0
       ) u
JOIN aitisi a ON a.id = u.id 
where a.id between 6017 and 6063
```

but in the results I'm getting IDs that are outside the between range.
Any chance I've placed the `WHERE m.extracard > 0` in the wrong place?

Comment: It seems to be good ... Maybe try wrapping the unioned selects like `(SELECT ...) UNION ALL (SELECT ...)`. BTW, `UNION` will remove duplicate elements (==slower), `UNION ALL` is faster, and keeps duplicates.

Comment: Your query looks strange. First you select records from `aitisi` with your desired `id`s, then you union some members, again joining `aitisi` but leaving additional columns `NULL`, just to join `aitisi` once more and re-populate those missing columns. If you would mind to explain what you expect from your query, we might be able to come up with an easier approach...

Comment: PLease have a look, I've posted the related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127012/mysql-union-how-do-i-show-table-1-content-in-all-rows

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.onoma_u, u.name_u,
coalesce(u.programa, a.programa) as programa,
coalesce(u.barcode, a.barcode) as barcode,
coalesce(u.plan, a.plan) as plan,
coalesce(u.im_exp, a.im_exp) as im_exp,
coalesce(u.symb, a.symb) as symb
FROM (SELECT a1.id, a1.onoma_u, a1.name_u, a1.programa, 
             a1.barcode, a1.plan, a1.im_exp, a1.symb
      FROM aitisi a1 
      JOIN mwmbers m ON a1.id = m.symbid 
           WHERE m.extracard > 0
      where a1.id between 6017 and 6063
      UNION
           SELECT a2.id, m.name, m.surname, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
           FROM members m 
           JOIN aitisi a2 ON a2.id = m.symbid 
           WHERE m.extracard > 0
       ) u
JOIN aitisi a ON a.id = u.id 
where a.id between 6017 and 6063
```